# Understanding git-svn configuration

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, git-config

`git-svn` man page has this example:

```
[svn-remote "project-a"]
        url = http://server.org/svn
        fetch = trunk/project-a:refs/remotes/project-a/trunk
```

So, as I understand it, it configures the svn to fetch changes from `http://server.org/svn/trunk/project-a`, which is a result of concatenation of the relative path of `trunk/project-a` and the root url, which is `http://server.org/svn`. Is this correct?

Also, I am confused by the `:` separator in the `fetch`. Does it serve as a separator of elements in the list, or a tuple?

And finally, why is `trunk/project-a` repeated twice in this list, and why does it have `refs/remotes` the second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch`'s value is a refspec, which consists of a remote and a local part. The part on the left of the colon is the path in the remote (SVN) repository, while the part on the right of the colon is the corresponding ref in the local (git) repository. You can find more information on the `git-config` (remote.*), and `git-fetch` manpages. I seem to recall there were some differences in `git-svn` handling of wildcards from git's normal wildcard handling in refspecs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you explain the difference between `fetch` and `branches` variables there?